# Ideal robots.txt for a gitweb installation?

Tags: robots.txt, git

I host a few git repositories at git.nomeata.de using gitweb (and gitolite). Occasionally, a search engine spider comes along and begins to hammer the interface. While I generally do want my git repositories to show up in search engines, I do not want to block them completely. But they should not invoke expensive operations such as snapshotting the archive, searching or generating diffs.

What is the “best” `robots.txt` file for such an installation?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this makes a good community wiki. Please extend this robots.txt if you think it can be improved:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /*a=search*
Disallow: /*/search/*
Disallow: /*a=blobdiff*
Disallow: /*/blobdiff/*
Disallow: /*a=commitdiff*
Disallow: /*/commitdiff/*
Disallow: /*a=snapshot*
Disallow: /*/snapshot/*
Disallow: /*a=blame*
Disallow: /*/blame/*
```

Comment: I've found that depending on how gitweb is configured, these URLs are not enough; e.g. in my installation, I needed to add for each `/.*a=xxx*` an entry of the type `/*/xxx/*`.